# Disrupt a linear one to one map $L_0$ gives a linear one to one map $L_t$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

> I have a continuous function $f$ from $[0,1]\to\mathcal{L}(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^p)$ such that $f(t)=L_t.$
>
> Assume that $L_0$ is one ton one, I would like to prove that $L_t$ is one to one for $t$ sufficiently small.

Set $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\gamma>0$ such that for any $t\in[0,\gamma)$ we have
$$\Vert L_t-L_0\Vert<\varepsilon$$

Now for any $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$ I have $\Vert (L_t-L_0)(x)\Vert\le \Vert L_t-L_0\Vert  \Vert x\Vert$

In fact, I am not sure how can I use the linearity here.

If $x\ne0$ I can choose $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{\Vert x\Vert}$, I will have $\Vert L_t(x)-L_0(x) \Vert<1$ for $t\in [0,\gamma)$, not sure that help.

*Geometrically* I cannot see why $L_t$ will be one to one, I can imagine that $L_t(x)$ is equal to $L_0(t)+\vec{v}$ and the norm of linear map can be visualize as the taking the biggest vector on the unit sphere.

> Question: Can someone give a nice *view* of why is going to be one to one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice first that that there exists $c$ such that $\|L_0(x)\| > c >  0$ for all vectors $x$ such that $\|x\| =1$. 
This holds since $L_0$ is linear (which implies $L_0(0) = 0$),  $L_0$ is one-to-one, and the set $\{ x : \|x\| = 0\}$ is closed.

Thus linearity implies that $\|L_0(x)\| \geq c \|x\|$ for any vector $x$.

Continuity says that there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $t < \delta$, then $\|L_t - L_0 \| \leq c/2$.

Then for $t < \delta$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\| L_t(x) - L_t(y) \|  &= \|L_t(x-y)\| \\
&\geq \| L_0(x-y)\| - \|[L_t -L_0](x-y) \| \\
&\geq c\|x-y\| - c/2(\|x - y\|) \\
&= c/2\|x-y\|\\
& > 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad  \text{ if } x \neq y,
\end{align*}
so $L_t$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Your solution is a bit confusing, my problem is that I don't see where you are using the fact that $L_t$ is linear, it's seems that your proof will works for any continuous maps.

Comment: Apologies -- the proof I gave earlier was wrong. I believe it's correct now. And it now uses linearity extensively.